# Couchdb view query crash/time out

Tags: erlang, debian, couchdb

I have setup couchdb on a debian 8 64 bit instance.

When I query one of the views, it times out from curl point of view.

Following is what I see form couch.log:

```
[Thu, 24 Dec 2015 07:17:23 GMT] [info] [<0.173.0>] Starting index update for db: notes idx: _design/notes
[Thu, 24 Dec 2015 07:17:23 GMT] [error] [<0.180.0>] ** Generic server <0.180.0> terminating
** Last message in was {prompt,[<<"reset">>,
                                {[{<<"reduce_limit">>,true},
                                  {<<"timeout">>,5000}]}]}
** When Server state == {os_proc,"/usr/local/bin/couchjs /usr/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js",
                                 #Port<0.2840>,
                                 #Fun<couch_os_process.2.3888802>,
                                 #Fun<couch_os_process.3.3888802>,5000}
** Reason for termination ==
** {badarg,[{erlang,port_command,
                    [#Port<0.2840>,
                     [<<"[\"reset\",{\"reduce_limit\":true,\"timeout\":5000}]">>,
                      10]],
                    []},
            {couch_os_process,writejson,2,
                              [{file,"couch_os_process.erl"},{line,93}]},
            {couch_os_process,handle_call,3,
                              [{file,"couch_os_process.erl"},{line,183}]},
            {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,580}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}

[Thu, 24 Dec 2015 07:17:23 GMT] [error] [<0.180.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                     {<0.180.0>,crash_report,
                      [[{initial_call,{couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}},
                        {pid,<0.180.0>},
                        {registered_name,[]},
                        {error_info,
                         {exit,
                          {badarg,
                           [{erlang,port_command,
                             [#Port<0.2840>,
                              [<<"[\"reset\",{\"reduce_limit\":true,\"timeout\":5000}]">>,
                               10]],
                             []},
                            {couch_os_process,writejson,2,
                             [{file,"couch_os_process.erl"},{line,93}]},
                            {couch_os_process,handle_call,3,
                             [{file,"couch_os_process.erl"},{line,183}]},
                            {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,580}]},
                            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]},
                          [{gen_server,terminate,6,
                            [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,737}]},
                           {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                            [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},
                        {ancestors,
                         [couch_query_servers,couch_secondary_services,
                          couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
                        {messages,[{#Port<0.2840>,{exit_status,127}}]},
                        {links,[<0.95.0>]},
```

Could some couch experts help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> Note that if the result of a reduce function is longer than the initial values list then a Query Server error will be raised. However, this behavior can be disabled by setting reduce_limit config option to false

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html

Search the page for occurrences of `reduce_limit`.

Comment: To expand on this answer a bit: what the error says is that you have a reduce function that is not actually making the data smaller. Yes, you can disable the safety check, but you could end up with a very inefficient index. I would recommend that the OP ask a new question, about *why* the reduce function causes this error and how to design a more efficient index for the type of query needed.